# Find xml in the text or string

Tags: c#, xml

How can I find the xml snippet in the string or text? Does not matter what programming language to use, better is C#. It may be non standard xml text and the string/text may like this:

```
checkLicense: A Boolean attribute that specifies that a WOPI server SHOULD enforce license restrictions for file types within the ct_app-name block. 


<xs:complexType name="ct_app-name">    
    <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="action" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ct_wopi-action"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="favIconUrl" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="checkLicense" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/> 
</xs:complexType>


The ct_wopi-action complex type specifies an action (such as viewing a file) that a WOPI client can perform.
```

Comment: "It may be non standard xml text" so how do you expect to identify the XML? Look for a starting tag and an end tag? You're going to have to deal with attributes, namespaces, CDATA, empty tags (`<tagname/>`), etc.

Comment: What you have there is an *XSD* - which is XML, but probably not how you're thinking of it.

Comment: I want to use the start tag and end tag to find it, but I do not know the tagname. It's like a snippet of a copy from an XML file, but there must be a start and end tag, except there may be no root and xml head. I want to find out the xml snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague (and a bit of a moving target)

However, if you want everything between `<` and `>` you could just use `regex` with some greediness

```
@"\<.*\>"
```

Example

```
var pattern = @"\<.*\>";
var xml = @"blah blah blah
            dsfsdf,<d [j>ohn]
            ZXZx<John >Johnson
            sdfdsfdsf";
var match = Regex.Match(xml , pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline;

if (match.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0]);
}
```

However if you want to match a more specific tag you use a pattern like this

```
@"\<xs:complexType.*\</xs:complexType>"
```

In both cases `match.Groups[0]` will return your `xml`, and `match.Success` determine if you have any

[You can test it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j1ULpS)